# How to generate import at compile time?

Tags: java, code-generation, jdk-internal-api

I am currently doing this with the implementation of `com.sun.source.util.Plugin`, which has this method for adding the following expression to the import section `import java.util.List;`:

```java
private void generateImport(CompilationUnitTree compilationUnitTree) {
        var jcCompilationUnit = (JCTree.JCCompilationUnit) compilationUnitTree;
        List<JCTree> imports = jcCompilationUnit.defs.stream()
            .filter(def -> def.hasTag(JCTree.Tag.IMPORT))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        JCTree.JCImport classImport = treeMaker.Import(
            treeMaker.Select(
                treeMaker.Ident(names.fromString("java.util")),
                names.fromString("List")
            ),
            false
        );
        imports.add(classImport);
        jcCompilationUnit.defs = List.from(imports);
    }
```

**names** - Instance of `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Names` & **treeMaker** - Instance of `com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeMaker`

I added my plugin as a dependency to a project with one single `A.java`, and after the `mvn package` is done, `A.class` is missing, I just have an empty `target` directory.

It seems like my solution is wrong.
So the question is: how do I add `import <something>` to `A.java` at compile time?

P.S. I was looking for ways to add imports in projects such as *Lombok*, *MapStruct*, *Spoon* and other less well-known, but I did not find anything like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works except the part where you ignored the Package declaration.
With your solution, generated import statement will be above the package declaration and it cause compilation error.
If you arrange the line of the import that you generated then it works.
Thanks for the solution.